# How to upload svg iamges in CMS pages in magento 2

Tags: cms, magento2.2.2, svg

I wish to add svg images in cms pages in backend.
While uploading .svg images, it shows invalid file.
Please provide me a solution to upload svg images in cms pages in magento 2

Answer (score 0):

The extensions are hard coded in

```
vendor/magento/module-catalog/Controller/Adminhtml/Product/Gallery/Upload.php:47
```

Third, you need to use the IMAGEMAGICK adapter.

FOSS extension to fix that (self-promotion): `https://github.com/iMi-digital/magento2-module-svg-product-images`